# End-to-end test on web application with Cypress: simulating clicks

Tags: testing, vuejs3, cypress, mouseevent

I have written an application that uses the vue3 component vue3-chessboard.
You may see the component at

```
https://qwerty084.github.io/vue3-chessboard/
```

If the user right clicks on a square of the chessboard a circle should appear around the selected piece. I want to write a test that simulates clicks on different pieces

I have written many variations of the following script to simulate a right-click

```
describe('Click Test', () => {
    it('clicking', () => {
      cy.visit('https://qwerty084.github.io/vue3-chessboard/')
      cy.url().should('include', 'http');
      // wait a second just in case
      cy.wait(1000);
      // click on the piece in the 4th position
      cy.get('piece').eq(4).rightclick({ force: true });
      // click on the piece in the 20th position
      cy.get('piece').eq(20).rightclick({ force: true });
   });
})
```

but unfortunately the script does not work.

After the test execution if I hover over the last executed line: "-rightclick(force=True)"
a little red sphere appears on the chessboard on the right coordinates so the element is found and the rightclick command is executed but not circle appears.

Any help with this problem will be welcomed.

=====

Thanks to "Lola" I was able to write the following script

> describe('Login Test', () => {   it('clicking', () => {
> cy.viewport(1200,1500)  // to avoid scrolling problems
>
> ```
> cy.visit('https://qwerty084.github.io/vue3-chessboard/')
>
> cy.get('circle[cgHash*="green"]').should('not.exist')  // no green circle yet
>
> cy.get('piece').eq(20)
> .trigger('mousedown', {button:2, position: 'center'})
> cy.get('piece').eq(20)
> .trigger('mouseup', {button:2, position: 'center'})
>
> cy.get('circle[cgHash*="green"]').should('be.visible')   })
> ```

Then I tried to move a piece, that is, with the left bottom click on the "origin" square and then on the "target" square. The test did not work :-(. Follows the script

```
describe('Login Test', () => {
    it('clicking', () => {
        // app code
        let f = 1.3 // scale factor. you may need to modify it
        let x_inc = 59.5*f
        let y_inc = 59.5*f
        let x0 = 28*f
        let y0 = 28*f

        cy.viewport(1200,1500)  // to avoid scrolling problems
  
        cy.visit('https://qwerty084.github.io/vue3-chessboard/')
  


  cy.get('cg-board')
    .trigger('mousedown', {button:1, x: x0+4*x_inc, y: y0 + 6*y_inc})
    cy.get('cg-board')
    .trigger('mouseup',   {button:1, x: x0+4*x_inc, y: y0 + 6*y_inc})
    cy.get('cg-board')
    .trigger('mousedown', {button:1, x: x0+4*x_inc, y: y0 + 5*y_inc})
    cy.get('cg-board')
    .trigger('mouseup',   {button:1, x: x0+4*x_inc, y: y0 + 5*y_inc})

    })
})
```

again any help will be welcomed

Answer (score 4):

Enabling the click turns out to be relatively easy, you can just trigger a `mousedown`.

If you look in the devtools, you can can see there are three event handlers on the `<cg-board>` element (none on the `<piece>` element within).

- `contextmenu` - presume this disables the standard browser right-click, since that doesn't pop up anymore
- `mousedown` - for selecting the element
- `touchstart` - likewise

The Cypress `.rightClick()` does also trigger a `mousedown`, but doesn't work because either it doesn't bubble from `<piece>` to `<cg-board>`, or there is a problem with target coordinates.

You should also assert that the green circle appears.

```js
it('clicking', () => {
  cy.viewport(1200,1500)  // to avoid scrolling problems

  cy.visit('https://qwerty084.github.io/vue3-chessboard/')

  cy.get('circle[cgHash*="green"]').should('not.exist')  // no green circle yet

  cy.get('piece').eq(4)
    .trigger('mousedown', {button:2, position: 'center'})

  cy.get('circle[cgHash*="green"]').should('be.visible')
})
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answer. I needed to modify the proposed script a bit but it works. The modification introduced was to add the line 
  cy.get('piece').eq(4)
    .trigger('mouseup', {button:2, position: 'center'})  after the line 
  cy.get('piece').eq(4)
    .trigger('mousedown', {button:2, position: 'center'}). Now I tried to move a piece instead of just selecting it and I fail :-(. I have edited my question describing the new problem

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by "lola" works for circle drawing but not for piece moving. I finally found an answer to the piece moving problem.

By design, chessground (which is the java-script module that vue3-chessboard uses to draw the chess board) tries to restrict interaction to human input avoiding robots. So the solution is to include the option

```
{
  ...
  trustAllEvents:true,
  ...
}
```

when the board is created. With this flag the test behave as spected.